# Include more then one testng xmls in one testng xml

Tags: java, testng

I have many testng files, each having more than ten class calling tests. I want to include all the testng files in one file. One way is to copy all the content and paste in one testng xml, But the problem here is the xml becomes to long.
Do testng/java have any other technique to do this?

Comment: One way to get rid of a long file is to split it into many smaller ones. Oh wait... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have a master suite of all your suites.

```
<suite name="Suite of suites">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="src/test/resources/another.xml"></suite-file>
        <suite-file path="src/test/resources/andanother.xml"></suite-file>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```